# Hibernate do a projection of count alias

Tags: java, hibernate, subquery, projection

Here is my code:

```
class A {
     Integer id
     String name
     Set<B> bs;

     //Getters and setters
}

class B {
     Integer id;
     A a;

     //Getters and setters
}
```

I need do a consult to get all rows of A, and for each row need know how many B reference to A.

I have a SQL query, but I don't know how do it with hibernate in Java

Simplified query:

```
select
    a.ID as y0_,
    (select count(*) 
     from B b 
     where b.c47 = a.ID 
       and b.FDL = 'N') as count,
from
    A a 
inner join
    C c on a.operario = c.ID 
where
    a.DID = 2
    and a.FDL = 'N'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a_table")
class A
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;

    @Column 
    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    Set<B> bs;

     //Getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "b_table")
class B
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    A a;

     //Getters and setters
}
```

The HQL:

```
select a.id, count(bs)
from A a
left join a.bs bs
inner join a.c c
where 
    a.id = 2 
    and a.FDL='N'
    and bs.FDL='N'
```

Comment: Yes, my classes are like this, but for simplicity I remove all attributes and annotations. Only I can do whit HQL?Can I use Criteria?

Comment: I presume it is possible to do it with criteria but I'm not so familiar with it. I guess it is for another question :)